# How to get regular expressions working in the filter clause in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I cant seem to get the  filter clause to retrieve documents from my index using a regex clause. The schema for my index is straight forward, I only have a single field which is both searchable and filterable and is of type Edm.String, called someId (which normally contains a hash value of something) and has sample values like:

*someId*

k6l7k2oj

k6l55iq8

k6l61ff8
...

I need to be able to extract all values from this field that start with K6 and end with 8. So based on the documentation I am using this in my POST request body

{
"filter": "search.ismatch('/^k6[?]*d$/','someId','simple','all')",

"select":"someId",

"count":"true"

}
and it comes up with nothing.
On the other hand if I simplify and say I only need data where someId starts with K6, I seem to get some success if i just use a wild card.
like this:

{
"filter": "search.ismatch('k6l*','someId','simple','all')",

"select":"someId",

"count":"true"

}
I do get what I am looking for. Question is why does the regex not work with search.isMatch(), what am i missing?

...

Answer (score 1):

Regex is part of the full Lucene syntax; It is not available in the simple syntax. Try changing the third parameter of `search.ismatch` to `'full'`.

Also, did you mean to use `search.ismatch` or `search.ismatchscoring`? The latter is functionally equivalent to using the top-level `search`, `searchFields`, `queryType`, and `searchMode` parameters. The former does not count matches towards relevance scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not do what you intend either it seems. I tested your regex with your sample data and it does not match. Try this regex instead:

```
^k6.{5}8$
```

It matches a lowercase k6 from the start of the string, followed by 5 characters of anything and finally an 8.

Complete example

```
{ "filter": "search.ismatch('^k6.{5}8$','someId','full','all')", "select":"someId", "count":"true" }
```

[image: Example from Regex Hero]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dan and Bruce.
This exact expression worked for me

{
"filter": "search.ismatch('/k6.{5}8/','someId','full','all')",
"select":"someId",
"count":"true"

}